# Como re-criar tabela no sql pelo Entityframework

Tags: entity-framework-6

Deletei uma tabela diretamente no banco de dados, realizei o comando do update-database no PackManager Console porém a tabela não foi criada novamente. Qual comando devo utilizar para recriar essa tabela?

Answer (score 1):

Esta não é a maneira correta de realizar este procedimento. O correto seria reverter a migração usando o comando:

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration:NomeDeUmaMigracaoAnteriorSemOPontoCS
```

Se quer reverter tudo, use:

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration:0
```

Note que a reversão executa todos os métodos `Down` das `Migrations` selecionadas para reversão. Portanto, pode ser que não apenas a tabela em questão seja excluída, como outras alterações também.